# What are 'tags' referring to in the Azure API app settings?

Tags: azure, appsettings, azure-api-apps

I'm not sure what 'tags' are referring too in the API App settings, I wondered if I might be able to set App Settings anywhere and if this was that ability but I am not sure and cannot find any documentation on this. Any help is much appreciated.

[image]

Comment: Azure resource manager allows you to use tags to organize all your Azure resources.  https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/resource-group-using-tags/

Comment: @BenV put your comment as an answer so it can be accepted. You may add that these tags will appear in the billing also, so you can gain better perception about your usage and where the money actually go :)

Comment: @astaykov I always feel a little guilty about one-sentence answers :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Azure Resource Manager allows you to use tags to organize all your Azure resources.  This allows you to group and filter resources in the [Preview Portal](https://portal.azure.com), and will also allow you to slice and dice your usage and billing information by tag.

https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/resource-group-using-tags/